# ActiveModel Serializer JSONAPI included resource

Tags: active-model-serializers, rails-api, json-api

I am working with ActiveModel Serializer's JSONAPI adapter and I'm trying to include a "user" resource when I serialize a "video" resource. Currently my video serializer looks something like this:

```
class VideoSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :uploaded_at, :title, :description

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  included :user
end
```

I've spent some time looking through the recently closed issues here: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues and it looks like this feature should be complete in the latest release I just can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `included` method defined in the serializer DSL. There is, though, an `included` *adapter* option, that allows one to specify which related resources should be included in the response document.

In your case (in your controller):

```
render json: videos, adapter: :json_api, include: 'user'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @beauby!